# Unity 2D how do I prevent an object from rotating based on world coordinates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a top down 2D game. The player needs to be able to shoot arrows so inside the Player prefab I have an empty object for FirePoint and Crosshair (picture 3). I have a script for the crosshair that follows the mouse position. I have an empty object that is a child component of the player called FirePoint. All this is for is the location of instantiation for the arrow prefab.

PROBLEM: This firepoint object seems to rotate around based on the position in the world. Notice picture 1 the character is in the bottom left area, the red axis should be pointing up and to the right at the cursor, but instead points down and to the left. Then in picture 2 its the bottom right corner. The same issue for top right/left part of the map. I need this fire point to not rotate based on world position.

If the character is at 0,0 it works just fine. But as soon as I move positions the fire point will rotate based on world position and then screw up my shooting.

How do I prevent all rotation since I have the script to follow the cursor? Why is it rotating based on world position? Why does an empty object rotate based on world position?

[image: FirePoint Transform 1]
[image: FirePoint Transform]
[image: FirePoint Transform 3]

```
void Update()
{
    Vector2 mouseCursorPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    transform.position = mouseCursorPos;
    
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(mouseCursorPos.y, mouseCursorPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
}
```

Comment: To just get the direction, can't you just take the clicked point and the player's position, subtract them and normalize it? That would give you the direction vector pointing at the location that was clicked regardless of any other angles/positions.

Comment: As rightly said in the above comment by @TEEBQNE, that should be the way to go, since child transforms are bound to rotate with the parent transform. Moreover, it would be wise to capture the reference of `Camera.main` in some local variable instead of calling it in `Update` method.